# How to verify that a function is a pmf of a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability

I am preparing for a prob/stats exam and have encountered this practice question:
[image]

I am confused about what it means to "verify that $p(x)$ is a pmf of a discrete random variable" for a few reasons:

1. A pmf, by definition, is a function that gives the probability of a discrete random variable...
2. It literally shows that the values x can take are discrete.

Do I need to use probability axioms or something? Is there some notational description of a pmf I need to compare this to?

Comment: Hint: a pmf must sum to $1$. (And, of course, its values must be nonnegative.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a discrete random variable you have to verify that $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} p(x) =1$.
In doing so remember the geometric series $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{4})^x=\frac{4}{3}$.

Similarly, if you had to verify that some function $f$ represented a pdf you would have to show that $\int f(x) dx=1$